# Laravel continous development for production site

Tags: laravel, production, migrate

I develop a laravel site in localhost. I'm very interested in the best way to migrate database to production site without losing current data.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using phpmyadmin you can just export the database. It will create a .sql file. Then you need to go into the phpmyadmin of your server and import this .sql file.

Answer (score 0):

You can just save local database with `mysqldump` to file on the localhost and restore it from dump on the remote one, using ssh (by `mysql host database < dump.sql`) or phpmyadmin kind of tool.

Answer (score -2):

Backup your database and storage;
Use a git repository- BitBucket or GitHub;

Any more information on your production server? Development Server?
Example: XAMPP, WAMP, or other local server

Are you going to use LAMP?